# Youtube Video Embed Issue in Magento 2 2.4 ( Blog Post Section )

Tags: video, youtube

[image: This content is blocked. contact the site owner to fix the issue. iframe]

I Insert this code on the Magento panel blog post section.

> 

The content is blocked, I don't understand what is the issue? any one guide me how to solve this with free resource? i fond some paid plugin but i need free solution. THanks!

Comment: Did you check in your browser console if it's not related to a CSP issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure Google Youtube API in configuration catalog section.

Please refer below link:

[Youtube Inegration](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/product-video.html)